# How to show that the spectrum is equal to the range of $y$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

How to show that the spectrum of $T_y$ is equal to the range of $y$

Given $y\in C[0,1]$ and $T_y: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]: x\mapsto x\cdot y$

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: should the spectrum not just consist of elements of $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, I didn't think it would contain functions?

Comment: @ellya $y:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, so its range is real/complex numbers.

Comment: @Neal oh I see, I misread it as the range of $T_y$, I don't know why though.. it clearly states range of $y$..

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint:

$$u\mapsto (\lambda - T_y)u = \lambda u - y u = (\lambda - y)u$$

is invertible for which $\lambda$?